# How to best optimize a function with a nested for-loop

Tags: javascript, memory, optimization

I have a `function` that has a nested `for loop`. As the `function` iterates over more data, it is starting to slow down. How can I best optimize this function so that it runs a bit faster?

```
function rubicoGVB(arr, range) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) / range < 16487665) {
                res.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return res.length;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a better fit at https://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: 1. Cache 'length' property

2. Use ES6 'let' variables (instead of var i, var j type let i and let j).

Comment: if you only want to return length you don't need res array

Comment: @reski: Depending on how you used `let` in the above, it would either make no difference whatsoever, or it would slow it down. It wouldn't speed it up.

Comment: @FastSnail: **OMG** I totally missed that. That would make the biggest improvement.

Comment: How about `res.push()`, will splitting `res` to `res[i]` make any difference? Like mysql insert, when there are more records the insert gets slower? Just wondering.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: Well you couldn't assign to `res[i]` as `i` grows even when `res` doesn't and `res` grows even when `i` doesn't. You could do `res[res.length] = ...` but whether that's better than `push` depends on the JavaScript engine you use. But see FastSnail's comment above: As the OP is just returning `res.length` the entire `res` array is pointless.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes I saw that, and that'll be the biggest improvement, but I couldn't keep myself to ask that it make a difference or not. I meant in the first loop, just call `res[i] = []` and then in the third loop, push with `res[i].push(arr[i]);`.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: Why create multiple arrays?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder like I said in my first comment, when the array gets bigger does the push gets slower?

Comment: @TahaPaksu: Not in any way that would be improved by creating additional arrays.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what the function is *supposed* to compute, and how its inputs look like (e.g. is `range` always a positive integer)? If your data is sorted, you could speed up the counting significantly - to the point where it might be worth to sort it

Comment: https://jsperf.com/array-range-count/1 created a perf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The biggest improvement you could make is described by Fast Snail [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238732/how-to-best-optimize-a-function-with-a-nested-for-loop/47238756#comment81427561_47238732): You don't need the `res` array just to return its length; simply use a counter. Below are other improvements you could make.)

---

Looking at those loops, there's very little you can do other than:

1. Caching the length of the array, and
2. Caching `arr[i]` instead of looking it up repeated in the `j` loop

...which are minimal (but real) improvements, see `len` and `entry` below:

```
function rubicoGVB(arr, range) {
    var res = [];
    var len = arr.length;
    var entry;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        entry = arr[i];
        for (var j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if ((entry + arr[j]) / range < 16487665) {
                res.push(entry);
            }
        }
    }

    return res.length;
}
```

Comment: Don't compute the division every time

Comment: @Bergi: How would we (reasonably) avoid that, with the information we currently have?

Comment: Something like `var max = 16487665 * range` outside of the loop and  `entry + arr[j]  < max`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Put it on the other side of the comparison, and pre-compute that value

Comment: @OriDrori: Without knowing the range of values for `range`, we can't safely do that. But sure, if the range of `range` is reasonable...

Comment: @OriDrori: Right. But again: Unless we know the range of values `range` may have, we don't know that we can safely multiply it by 16487665 without passing `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: @OriDrori: As are you, since `range` would have to be pretty big for that to be an issue. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Probably `entry + arr[j]` is pretty large, and `range` rather small, or otherwise the predicate wouldn't make much sense in the first place. If venturing into the land of floating point inaccuracies will be a problem, it's likely a problem with the current code as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the help. I learned a lot from your suggestions. I now see that you I don't need `res` array, I can simply `return` a counter instead.